# cherrypy not exiting via cherrpy.system.exit

Tags: cherrypy

I'm trying to run the following simple cherrpy code, `gather_keys_oauth2`, located at:
https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/blob/master/gather_keys_oauth2.py

The important bit of code, I think, is essentially the following:

```
import cherrypy
import threading

class OAuth2Server:

    def __init__(self):
        self.param = 1

    def browser_authorize(self):
        """
        Open a browser to the authorization url and spool up a CherryPy
        server to accept the response
        """
        cherrypy.quickstart(self)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        """
        Receive a Fitbit response containing a verification code. Use the code
        to fetch the access_token.
        """
        self.param = 2  
        #This doens't work either:
        #threading.Timer(1, cherrypy.engine.exit).start()
        cherrypy.engine.exit()
        return "<h1>wtf</h1>"

s = OAuth2Server()
s.browser_authorize() #hanging here

#Currently this doesn't run, hangs at the previous line
print('hooray! this ran') 

#Note, in reality I want to run more code here
```

Once you run the code, navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and it should run the kill code, but the code never quits, so I never get my 'hooray!' message afterwards. Why can't I stop cherrypy from blocking code execution? This is on a mac using Spyder, Python 3.8, and cherrypy 18.6.0.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, the goal is to be able to continue execution in the main Python thread after the kill command, with variables from the cherrpy code being accessible in the main thread.

This is what I see (from the threading.Timer call. It just hangs at that last message.

```
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:24] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) shut down
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE Bus EXITED
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
[23/Jan/2021:00:13:29] ENGINE Waiting for thread Thread-4.
```

Comment: Did you start a thread? I don't see one here.
Since the cherrypy engine did stop, meaning the main thread is down, you seem to have a zombie thread. Maybe daemonize it so it'll automatically die when the main one does.

Comment: What you see is what I'm running but I realized from your comment my goal was confusing so the question has been updated. The goal is to keep running Python code after the kill command, which if you look at the code in this example is just to run the `print` statement at the very end.

Comment: Admittedly, maybe I still don't know what you want, because all this is still not worded well and contradicting itself.
But if you want the cherrypy to die while the rest continues on, then you want to daemonize the CherryPy thread, seperating it from the main thread.
Cherrypy's Daemonizer is documented here: https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/3.2.6/refman/process/plugins/daemonizer.html